# Reverse Range Successors

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a positive integer `n`, do the following (and output every stage):

1. start with a list containing `n` copies of `n`.
2. do the following `n` times:
3. at the `i`th step, gradually decrement the `i`th entry of the list until it reaches `i`

So, for example, if the given `n` is `4`, then you start with `[4,4,4,4]`, and then at the first step you have `[3,4,4,4]`, `[2,4,4,4]`, `[1,4,4,4]`. At the second step, you have `[1,3,4,4]`, `[1,2,4,4]`. At the third step you have `[1,2,3,4]`. Nothing is done on the fourth step.

So your output is `[[4,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[1,4,4,4],[1,3,4,4],[1,2,4,4],[1,2,3,4]]`.

---

Any reasonable input/output format is permitted.

---

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): the answer with the smallest byte-count wins.

---

[Python implementation for checking purposes](https://tio.run/##XY3BCsIwEETP6VestwRRKHoS8iUhSKEbu2C3IY1Yvz7uigfxOPOGN/lVp4VPrY2YIFl2l87MOIOHwJCWAlcghjLwDQXGzhRcFYbtQzelso9CNNPvWlTmOdEddREows4D7Xutzbc5eOg1ivU45Iw82n@z08/6KOLFteVCXG2yZ@faGw).

Comment: You might want to explicitly state that `i`th is always 1-indexed.

Comment: Do we really have to manipulate array? I get to a shorter answer without manipulating any array, producing an acceptable output.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You do not have to follow the steps, you just need to produce the output in a reasonable format. (i.e. go ahead)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
r€⁸Œp»\QṚ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//cuKCrOKBuMWScMK7XFHhuZr///81)**

#### How?

```
r€⁸Œp»\QṚ - Link: integer, N    e.g. 4
 €        - for €ach of implicit range of N (i.e. for i in [1,2,3,...N])
  ⁸       -   with the chain's left argument, N on the right:
r         -     inclusive range (for i<=N this yields [i, i+1, ..., N]
          - ...leaving us with a list of lists like the post-fixes of [1,2,3,....,N]
          -                     e.g. [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4],[3,4],[4]]
   Œp     - Cartesian product* of these N lists
          -                     e.g. [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,4],[1,3,3,4],[1,3,4,4],[1,4,3,4],[1,4,4,4],[2,2,3,4],[2,2,4,4],[2,3,3,4],[2,3,4,4],[2,4,3,4],[2,4,4,4],[3,2,3,4],[3,2,4,4],[3,3,3,4],[3,3,4,4],[3,4,3,4],[3,4,4,4],[4,2,3,4],[4,2,4,4],[4,3,3,4],[4,3,4,4],[4,4,3,4],[4,4,4,4]]
      \   - cumulative reduce with:
     »    -   maximum (vectorises)
          -                     e.g. [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,4],[1,3,4,4],[1,3,4,4],[1,4,4,4],[1,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]]
       Q  - de-duplicate        e.g. [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,4],[1,3,4,4],[1,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[4,4,4,4]]
        Ṛ - reverse             e.g. [[4,4,4,4],[3,4,4,4],[2,4,4,4],[1,4,4,4],[1,3,4,4],[1,2,4,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

* It may be easier to see what's going on with the Cartesian product used above with a different input:

```
the Cartesian product of [[0,1,2],[3,4],[5]]
is [[0,3,5],[0,4,5],[1,3,5],[1,4,5],[2,3,5],[2,4,5]]
```

Comment: You outgolfed the un-outgolf-able.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>83</s> <s>82</s> 74 bytes

```r
N=rep(n<-scan(),n);while({print(N);any(K<-N>1:n)})N[x]=N[x<-which(K)[1]]-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/38@2KLVAI89Gtzg5MU9DUydP07o8IzMnVaO6oCgzr0TDT9M6Ma9Sw9tG18/O0CpPs1bTL7oi1hZI2OgCFSZnaHhrRhvGxuoa/jf9DwA)

Instead of a double for-loop, a `while` loop is sufficient here: we find the first index where the list is greater than the index, and decrement there.

`K` has `TRUE` wherever `N[i]>i`, `which(K)` returns the true indices, and we take the first with `[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
R‘®¦<³S©$Ð¿Ṛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//UuKAmMKuwqY8wrNTwqkkw5DCv@G5mv///zQ)

Comment: 13 bytes without register: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4bi24bma4oCZVOG5qiTCpuG6uMOQwr/igbhf4bma////NA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 75 bytes

```js
f=(n,a=Array(n).fill(n))=>[[...a],...a.some(v=>v>++j,j=0)?f(a[j-1]--,a):[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcVRCsMgDADQ6yRUwwb9GsSxc4gfodVRcWZoEXZ6t/28l2VI39rxPm3VPc6ZGKoRfrQmH6hI6SjlN7LznogkmL/U9RVhsBtuWbLJfMF7AvHZXoO1RvDmQ5ib1q4lUtEnJFgR5xc)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 54 bytes

Prompts for screen input of integer

```
((⍴m)⍴n)-+⍀m←0⍪(-0,+\⌽⍳n-1)⊖((+/+/m),n)↑m←⊖(⍳n)∘.>⍳n←⎕
```

Outputs a matrix with each row representing the result of each step e.g. for 4:

```
4 4 4 4
3 4 4 4
2 4 4 4
1 4 4 4
1 3 4 4
1 2 4 4
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 135 bytes

```java
a->{int r[]=new int[a],i=0;java.util.Arrays x=null;x.fill(r,a);for(r[0]++;i<a;r[i++]++)for(;--r[i]>i;System.out.print(x.toString(r)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY8xbsMwDEX3nIKjBMdChqYdVAfoAZolo6CBdexCriIblJw4MHx2l3Yzdcr2yf9JPjZ4xbztqtCcf@bSY4zwiS6MGwAXUkU1lhUcx2vrzkCCW4BST@zGhMmVcIQABcyYH8bFJGOLUN2WWYN264qdbviC6pPz6oMI7xGGIvTe60HVzntBW15YtyTI7GyWafeOmozLMi7k0td5zrU9OH26x1RdVNsn1RFfEINK7Smx/BYkJXPNmsm6/ssz2QNwJb/wS@IvaSzK5TuAoEi8SL3q/6t9EA9nSe2fSr0@lXpb9bSZ5l8)

**Explanation:**

```java
int r[]=new int[a],i=0;    //Initialize array and loop counter
java.util.Arrays x=null;    //reduces the number of of “Arrays” needed from 3 to 1
x.fill(r,a);    //Sets each value in array length n to int n
for(r[0]++;i<a;r[i++]++)    //Increment everything!
  for(;--r[i]>i;    //If decremented array element is larger than element number:
     System.out.print(x.toString(r)));}    //Print the array
```

**Credit:**

-8 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech)!

-16 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

-1 byte thanks to [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26600/okx)!

Comment: [129 bytes](https://tio.run/##jU@5bsMwDN3zFewmwZWQAj0G1QX6Ac2S0fDAOnZAV5YMWk4RGM6vu/IxdcpGvouPNV5Q@bZ09elnoqb1HKCOmO4DWf3JjNfO7AqLXQdfSG7YAZALJVdYlHAYLp5OwCJCgNKMke0CBirgAA5SmFB9DJHMck5d@TtbM8zNmqsrslbwYzRyts@TxFR@jaJ0b5KE3tUNjZzBKCD1lD@kZI7XLpSN9n3QLUex2MKCP4a4nwVLKTm7KcqVMuNkYqe2/7ax01Zt6dzEZ8TqyHKU818ATrN4lmaZ/9@xTmzMrHq5S/V6l@ptmcfdOP0B).

Comment: The `import java.util.*;` is part of the byte-count I'm afraid. And @JonathanFrech's code can be golfed by 4 more bytes by putting the `,i=0` after the `r[]`, and changing `<-~a` to `<=a`. ([Try it online. **144 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/yb5f6r7g)) (and I changed `~-i` to `i-1` to make it more readable..)

Comment: [**139 bytes** by getting rid of the `import java.util.*;` by using `java.util.Arrays x=null;` and `x.fill` and `x.toString`.](https://tinyurl.com/yd26rzyk) (Note that your current solution is 155 bytes with the required `import java.util.*;`.)

Comment: Golf a byte by using `for(;r[i-1]>i;` rather than `for(;r[i-1]!=i;`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Another byte could be saved by golfing `++i<=a` to `i++<a`.

Comment: Another -2 byte changing the last part to `for(r[0]++;i<a;r[i++]++)for(;--r[i]>i;System.out.print(x.toString(r)));`. :) [Try it online **135 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/yd6jdaj7)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>69 67 65</s> 63 bytes

Recursive definition:

```
f 0=[[]]
f a=map(:(a<$[2..a]))[a,a-1..2]++[1:map(+1)x|x<-f$a-1]
```

Thanks to Laikoni for 2 bytes!

Comment: The second `map` is two bytes shorter with a list comprehension: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck7DoAgDADQ3VN0YIAgRIgTgZM0HTpIJH5i1IHBu6O@9c18LdO6tpZhSIhEXQZOGx8ySI4CvbVMSiH3bJy1nrRGF/53WtWnRpPFN9Q2LjskOM6y3yAgw9he "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
x`’Jḟḣ1Ʋ¦ÐĿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//eGDigJlK4bif4bijMcaywqbDkMS/////NA)

#### How it works

```
x`’Jḟḣ1Ʋ¦ÐĿ  Main link. Argument: n

x`           Repeat self; yield an array of n copies of n.
         ÐĿ  While the results are unique, repeatedly call the link to the left.
             Return the array of all unique results, including the initial value.
  ’     ¦      Decrement the return value at all indices specified by the chain
               in between.
       Ʋ         Combine the four links to the left into a monadic chain.
   J               Indices; yield [1, ..., n].
    ḟ              Filterfalse; remove all indices that belong to the return value.
     ḣ1            Head 1; truncate the result to length 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes

```python
n=int(input())
x=[n]*n;print(x)
for i in range(n):
    for j in[0]*(n-i-1):x[i]-=1;print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcu9CoAgFIbh3atw9AhC0WZ4JeLQ0M9p@BQxsKs3XXrHB970litiaQ2OURQjPUURieo8gsaa8uBK4ohZsmTIvOHcFcgK2Rt8d/ZT0AqGzUy2eg7Gzf/b2gc)

Comment: 1 space is enough to indent code in python. Removing unnecessary spaces and switching to python 2 saves 10 bytes: [check it out](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDk6vCNjovVivPuqAoM69EoYIrLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjT9OKSwEklgUUizaI1dLI083UNdS0qojOjNW1NYTp@//fDAA)

Comment: @DeadPossum, even though I know I could do better in Python 2, its soon going to be obsolete so I wanted to practice my Python 3 skills as most as possible.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 153 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczBCgIhEAbge09RyxyUbZft0MmVHqRiEVM0ZBzcImLx2U3vwfDD/Px85KjMF6pp36hfPuLeMkC@gZIqJfVdrA@BTUfAelxAks814mJQx4dhoPjY3bATQHISH@dD7WhugK@OugLdDxKoPzWxfcNQjfE/kk1YzVbXvcjZaBchibwrlp25KD8)

**Code**

```
function f($n){
$a=array_fill(0,$n,$n);$r=json_encode($a)."\n";$p=0;while($p<$n)
{if($a[$p]!=$p+1){$a[$p]--;$r.=json_encode($a)."\n";}else{$p++;}}echo$r;}
```

*Gonna try to lower the bytes, or finish the recursive function*

**Explanation**

```
function f($n){
  $a=array_fill(0,$n,$n);          #start with $nlength array filled with $n
  $r=json_encode($a)."\n";         #pushed to the string to output
  $p=0;                            #first position
  while($p<$n){                    #on position $n ($n-1) we do nothing
    if($a[$p]!=$p+1){              #comparing the position+1 to the value
     $a[$p]--;                     #it gets decreased by 1
     $r.= json_encode($a)."\n";    #and pushed
   } else {
     $p++;                       #when position+1 = the value,
   }                               #position is changed ++
  }
   echo $r;
  }
```

Comment: seems like you have some unnecessary whitespace so this should be [153 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcxBCsMgEAXQq6RhFkqakC66MtKDtCWIVbTIOJiWUoJnt7ovDB/m83nkqCwXqmnfqF8@YmcZIN9BSZWS@q7Wh8DmI2A9LiDJ5xZxNajjwzBQfOpv2AsgOYuP86F2tDTAV0ddge4HCTScmti@cazGJLu/SjZhM3udDyJno12EJHKx7MxF@QE) -- note that I don't know PHP.

Comment: yep, just realize, thank you, editing now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> 76 bytes

```python
i=input();l=[i]*i;print l
for x in range(i):
 while l[x]>x+1:l[x]-=1;print l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERD0zrHNjozVivTuqAoM69EIYcrLb9IoUIhM0@hKDEvPVUjU9OKS6E8IzMnVSEnuiLWrkLb0ArE0LU1hGn5/98EAA)

Bit wasteful having two `print` statements but I can't think of a better way at the moment.

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERD0zrHNjozVivTusLWwLqgKDOvRCHHOrUiNVmpPCMzJ1W3rsImJ7oi1gpE6NoawpTE5FVo2xrG5ClpZf7/bwIA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun
-2 bytes thanks to @JonathanFrech

```python
i=I=input()
l=[I]*I
exec"exec'print l;l[-i]-=1;'*max(~-i,2);i-=1;"*~-I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PW0zYzr6C0REOTK8c22jNWy5MrtSI1WQlEqBcUZeaVKORY50TrZsbq2hpaq2vlJlZo1Olm6hhpWmeCRJS06nQ9//83AwA)

Comment: `(I-1)` --> `~-I`

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PW0zYzr6C0REPTOsc22jNWy9M6tSI1WQlEqBcUZeaVKORY50TrZsbq2hpaq2vlJlZo1Olm6hhpWmeCRJS06nQ9//83AwA), initializing `i=I` and decrementing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 112 bytes

```java
n->{var s="";for(int i=1,k=n,j;i<=n;k=--k>i?k:n-++i+i)for(j=0;j++<n;)s+=(j<i?j:j>i?n:k)+(j<n?",":";");return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7BaoQwEAbgu08x5GQaDS0UCsbordBDT3tse0hdLRN1lCQKy@Kz22zXaw/DMMw/zGfNanJ77ncc58kFsHGWS8BBdgs1ASeSDyppBuM9vBukawLggwnYwBuF1yNTnoJD@qmgAw075dV1NQ68Zkx1k0uRAqB@ynpNmVVYalK9zvO@wrovKBcCBfJb0OpHZYUoSXEvdGpLrG1hY4yKnos4U80yVjDFuHJtWByBV9uuImpevoeIOmzrhGcYoze9yz6@DL/RAeIb@ANRpD6r2EoNL7ELweEeAThdfGhHOS1BzvE8DJR20szzcEmJS9fOg2naNDIy9kmMc/X/3bHbkltt@y8)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
+/\@,(#=)@i.&.-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/7X1Yxx0NJRtNR0y9dT0dP9rcinpKaingRSoK@go1FoppBVzcaUmZ@QrpCmY/AcA)

### Explanation

```
+/\@,(#=)@i.&.-  Input: n
              -  Negate n
          i.     Reverse of range [0, n)
       =           Identity matrix of order n
      #            Copy each row by the reverse range
              -  Negate
    ,            Prepend n
+/\              Cumulative sum of rows
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 49 bytes

```
.+
*
_
$`_,$= 
.{*\`_+,(_+)
$.1
0`(\b(_+),\2)_
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4srnkslIV5HxVaBS69aKyYhXltHI15bk0tFz5DLIEEjJgnE04kx0gSqA2ox/Q8A) Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
_
$`_,$=
```

Create a list of n copies of `i,n` where `i` is the index of the copy.

```
.
```

Don't print anything (when the loop finishes).

```
{
```

Loop until the pattern does not change.

```
*\`_+,(_+)
$.1
```

Temporarily delete the `i`s and convert the `n`s to decimal and output.

```
0`(\b(_+),\2)_
$1
```

Take the first list entry whose value exceeds its index and decrement it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>70</s> <s>67</s> 65 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 k=0;a=[n]*n
 while k<n-1:print(a);k+=a[k]==k+1;a[k]-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI0/Tiksh29bAOtE2Oi9WK49LoTwjMydVIdsmT9fQqqAoM69EI1HTOlvbNjE6O9bWNlvb0BrE0rU1/J@mYaL5HwA)

- (67) Converting to function: -3 bytes
- (65) Removing unneeded parentheses: -2 bytes

**Ungolfed version:**

```python
def f(n):
    k = 0
    a = [n] * n             # create n-item list with all n's
    while k < n - 1:        # iterate through columns 0..n-1
        print(a)            # print whole list
        if a[k] == k + 1:   # move to the next column when current item reaches k+1
            k += 1
        a[k] -= 1           # decrement current item
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>131</s> 141 bytes

```c
i,j,k,m[99];p(){for(k=0;m[k];printf("%d ",m[k++]));puts("");}f(n){for(j=k=m[n]=0;k<n;m[k++]=n);p();for(;j<n;j++)for(i=1;i++<n-j;m[j]--,p());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BboMwEETP9VesqCrZMTSkt8i4P4I4UDCJ7bAgbNRIEd9O141UdU@7ozcz2xXdrcXL/mqxu629gSrE3k7v10/2X1osXkjbbe5yn4/1@dyomYvHMC3c61KNtSeBqDjw7K2HjBgvZSOEmtcYeJYJtQ0cnw6nvR5rbMjoK1RPVKNIkSoBypHspBTpsPqkrJQVFo5Q1xRFThzl7VQHY2uRC3iwdNxBQ6kYS7a0n0pFWqXhIy2URxwM/C4Ug7@/XmiOB/j9HoKZ26WNdkL4MvHbGIRoQoSuDSbA4cg2xhYT1wVT0bb/AA)

This will work for all `n` upto 99. TIO truncates output. It can support arbitrarily larger `n` by changing size of array `m` as memory permits.

---

Following is limited to n=1..9 but is significantly shorter

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>89</s> 92 bytes

```c
i,j;char m[12];f(n){j=!puts(memset(m,n+48,n));for(;j<n;j++)for(i=1;i++<n-j;m[j]--,puts(m));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xbsMwDETn6iuYdJEiu6mLDilo90eCDKpDJxIi2pBkNEDgb3eldikX8h7ujn3d3wxf1mfL/W0@E7Qxne34cv0U/1GwfMlstZXD/moC@GPzdsJBsnq4bjPNKUpPPlKSvmL9fqhYKRzGING1jE5rVYTtGrRat1w79Ed3quvqL5rNy2o5gTeWpYKHKOIOHbyiECVa7gYzajv4yDs3ZhcM8q5QwG/LdqvwKc9@B1Mo@UiTCSbZkeGL0jcRQ6KYoDeRIuz2YhEiUJoDlzfL@gM)

Updated: Modified to avoid dependence on static initialization

Comment: Your `static/global initialization because multiple test cases` is not allowed, as functions have to be callable more than once.

Comment: @Jonathan Updated answers. I always wondered if this should be allowed, and couldn't make up my mind.

Comment: Here is the relevant meta post: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/73111

Comment: You could golf `m[j]--,p()` to `p(m[j]--)` and save a byte.

Comment: [128 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7BboMwEETP9VdsqCrZMTRpb5GhP4I4UDCJTbwg2yiRIvrrdN1KVfc0O3q7M13RXVs8b88Gu@vSayhD7M30evlg/y1v8EzeZnKbu/p0atTMR/EYJs@Vq0daiYgDz156yIgYpWyEUPMSA88yodaB4y8@c1u5Gptqd3PaBR25yzFHgm2JykopEmUqlF9WmaKgoJ2rbVMUhKwbpYBrDXIBD5aWO1RwVIylq6Tfjoq8soL3JOgdcTDwu1AM/uo80Rz28FMagp5b30YzIXzqeNMaIeoQoWuDDrA/sJUxr@PiMQWt2zc "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
{{x[y]-:1;x}\(,x#x),,/(|!x)#'!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nqrq6IroyVtfK0LqiNkZDp0K5QlNHR1@jRrFCU1ldsaL2f5qCyX8A)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 132 bytes

```
#(loop[R[(vec(repeat % %))]j(- % 2)i 0](if(> i j)R(recur(conj R(update(last R)i dec))(if(= i j)(- % 2)(dec j))(if(= i j)(inc i)i))))
```

I was hoping this to be shorter...

Less stateful but longer at **141** bytes:

```
#(apply map list(for[i(range %)](concat(repeat(nth(cons 0(reductions +(reverse(range %))))i)%)(range % i -1)(if(>(dec %)i)(repeat(inc i))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 101 bytes

```
def f(n):
 p=print;m=[n for_ in range(n)];p(m)
 for i in range(n):
    while m[i]>1+i:m[i]-=1;p(m)
```

I could probably golf more with the print, but I'm away from my computer and am not entirely sure of python 2's rules on setting a variable to print. I'll update later when I get to a computer or if someone clarifies in the comments.